# Python bitswap // Ethash algorithm

Tags: python, ethash

I just started looking into the Ethash algorithm and I saw this:

```
s = sha3_512(header + nonce[::-1])
```

The thing is that here, nonce is an integer, and they used `[::-1]` to bitswap it from big endian to little endian? My question is what python version allows this? Every single one I tested gave me an `__getitem__` not defined. As I also want to see in which version of python we can manipulate bits like this, I'm not searching for an alternative big to little endian conversion, I just want to know how did they get this working?

Also, in the algorithm, they say they combine header and nonce into a 64bit seed through this `sha3_512` call. So how should header and nonce be? as hex string? integers? Should I convert nonce to an hex string so it can easily be added to header? This line lost me in their algorithm :/

Source : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The thing is that here, nonce is an integer

I think it's actually of type [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range) - it's not a true numeric type like `int` is. So here `nonce` is being treated as a byte array.

> So how should header and nonce be? as hex string? integers?

As above. You could try using the [`bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) or [`bytearray()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) to convert what you have.

Comment: Ok, I got confused as they wrote `nonce = randint(0, 2**64)` , but I guess their code is given as an illustration only. Thanks !